# I need JSON format with values for Flot Chart plugin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, flot

I want to get data from mysql database to put it in a chart using Flot plugin, according to [docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) data format is an array of dots: `[ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]`. In my case I want to get date and sales values and put it in this array, so I made this:

```
<?php 
 $sql = "SELECT * from sales where YEAR(date)='2013'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql);
 $return = [];

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $return[] = [$row['date'],$row['amount']];
 }

 echo '{ "label": "Sales", "data":'. json_encode($return, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE).'}';
?>
```

I get result like this:

```
{ "label": "Sales", "data":[["2013-02-01","52"],["2013-03-01","40"],["2013-03-28","200"]]}
```

I try to bring this information via AJAX:

```
var sales;

    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/sales.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp)
        {
            sales = [$.trim(resp.data)];
            console.log(sales);
        }
    });
```

But unfortunately I don't get the same format, result in console is like this:

```
["2013-02-01,52,2013-03-01,40,2013-03-28,280"]
```

And I want to get the same format like this:

```
[["2013-02-01","52"],["2013-03-01","40"],["2013-03-28","200"]]
```

How can I fix it? I'd like some help.

Comment: `resp.data` is a 2 deep nested array - don't use methods that coerce an array to a string .. `resp.data` is exactly what you want

Comment: $trim??? what for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `json_encode`ing the whole object, rather than concatenating a string with a json_encode in PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array("label" => "Sales", "data" => $return));
```

and then instead of

```
sales = [$.trim(resp.data)];
```

just access the plain .data property:

```
sales = resp.data;
```

Comment: The correct sentence was: `echo json_encode(array("label" => "Sales", "data"=>$return));`